# Multiple fill() on a canvas context : rgba transparent colors change

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, fill

I work with Firefox. I have a problem with multiple objects on a canvas to be filled with a semi-transparent color rgba (....). It seems that the transparency coefficient is multiplied by itself at each fill(). Anyone has an idea of the cause and a suggestion to avoid this ? In the code, the variable singleStyleInit can be flipped from true to false to see two ways of programming, which give the same result. The grey circles should have the same look and the same transparency, be it over the window background or over the red bar : they don't !

```js
      let canvas = document.getElementById ("layer") ;
      canvas.width = 1000 ; canvas.height = 100 ;
      let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      // 1 red horizontal bar, 
      ctx.fillStyle = "red" ;
      ctx.fillRect (20, 30, 830, 40) ;
      // 8 grey transparent circles
      var singleStyleInit = true ;
      if (singleStyleInit) 
          ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(128,128,80,0.3)" ;
      for (var i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++) {
          ctx.beginPath ;
          ctx.arc (50 + 110 * i, 50, 45, 0, 2*Math.PI) ;
          if (!singleStyleInit) 
              ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(128,128,80,0.3)" ;
          ctx.fill() ;
      }
```

```css
body { 
    background-color: rgb(249, 249, 250) ;
}
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw ;  height: 100vh ;
}
canvas {
    position: absolute ;
    top: 0px ; left: 0px ; 
}
```

```html
  <div>
    <canvas id="layer"></canvas> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you never truly beginPath. You must call it with parentheses () `beginPath()`

Comment: Oh sh.... how could I miss that ! Thank you for your help.